# Declaration of constructor of class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am learning operator overloading in C++. Here is the problem I have: 
when I am using `Integer(int v)` instead of `Integer(int v) : value(v) {}`, I am getting linker error. I do not know why. Please help!

```
class Integer {
private:
    int value;
public:
    Integer(int v) : value(v) { }
    Integer operator++();
    Integer operator++(int);
    int getValue() { 
        return value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: You need to implement all of the functions. Linker is complaining about missing definition of unimplemented functions.

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong ?

If you define your class as follows:

```
class Integer {
private:
    int value;
public:
    Integer(int v);             // there's no body anymore 
    Integer operator++();
    Integer operator++(int);
    int getValue() { 
        return value;
    }
};
```

then, none of the functions (except `getValue()` ) and no constructor are defined.

Whenever you instantiate your class somewhere, the compiler will generate a call to the constructor. If the constructor is defined nowhere, the linker will complain.

### How to solve it ?

You have to provide a definition for all the functionsa rnd constructors that are needed, either in the class declaration:

```
class Integer {
    ...
public:
    Integer(int v) : value(v) { }    // the { ... } is the constructor body 
    ...
    }
};
```

or outside the class declaration:

```
Integer::Integer(int v)      // outside class definition you need Integer:: prefix
    : value(v)               // this constructs the value member 
{
    cout << "class constructed with value "<<v<<endl;         
}
```

In principle you should also define both operators, either in the class or outside.  However, as long as you don't use them, the linker will not complain.